# Detect iframe using Json-RPC communication

Tags: iframe, xpages, json-rpc

I´m try implementing this funcionality:

The xpage can be open from Sharepoint Portal or directly from application option interface. The problem is that portal Sharepoint the xpages opens in a Iframe and must be redimensioned.
To redimension the xpages I´m using a css that executes the redimension. The application knows if it opens in iframe, it executes javascript code in onclientload event of xpage. The communication between client and server side is using remote services with argument the information it´s a iframe or no. It works but executes after hrefs resource computation property of xpage. The question is there how change execution sequence? Or is there anyway to implement this funcionality?

Thanks a lot!

Marcus